# How to infer and convert dtypes in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dtype

Here is my sample dataframe. I would like to convert the `dtypes` to `boolean` in column `A` and `B`, `string` in `C` and `integer` in `D` and `E`.
I am trying to use panda's method `convert_dtypes()` but it returns `string` for every one. How can I "automatically" convert the types?

```
{'A': {0: nan,
      1: nan,
      2: nan,
      3: nan,
      4: nan,
      5: nan,
      6: nan,
      7: 'true',
      8: nan,
      9: 'true'},
     'B': {0: nan,
      1: nan,
      2: nan,
      3: nan,
      4: nan,
      5: nan,
      6: nan,
      7: 'true',
      8: nan,
      9: 'true'},
     'C': {0: 'CustomersData',
      1: 'CustomersData',
      2: 'CustomersData',
      3: 'CustomersData',
      4: 'CustomersData',
      5: 'CustomersData',
      6: 'CustomersData',
      7: 'TestData',
      8: 'CustomersData',
      9: 'CustomersData'},
     'D': {0: '4014',
      1: '4014',
      2: '4014',
      3: '4014',
      4: '4014',
      5: '4014',
      6: '4014',
      7: '500',
      8: '4014',
      9: '500'},
     'E': {0: '8',
      1: '8',
      2: '8',
      3: '8',
      4: '8',
      5: '8',
      6: '13',
      7: '13',
      8: '8',
      9: '13'}}
```

`df.convert_types().dtypes` gives:

```
A string
B string
C string
D string
E string
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html doesn't do what you think it does - it converts types from the "old" types to the corresponding "new" types that support `pd.NA` - when you load in the data, you should specify the specific dtypes you want

Comment: @ifly6 I get it as key-value columns for each request and this is the result of preprocessing. How can I infer and convert each column to the most appropriate dtype?

Comment: with the original object columns (ie before attempting to call `convert_dtypes`) try https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html.

Comment: @ifly6 no change. Same behaviour. Please advise.

Comment: you'll have to specify them explicitly then

Comment: The only way to solve it is: Save it as csv, load again and you get the right inference. @ifly6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367183/is-there-any-way-to-extract-the-dtype-conversion-functionality-from-pandas-rea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that worked for me is a "workaround" to save it as csv and load again.
Pandas read_csv infers the types of the columns and worked for me.
Will be happy to know if I can solve it without this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes) : it returns a new dataframe with columns as types guessed by pandas, the same way it does when loading from a csv.

See the example from the doc :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.dtype("int32")),
        "b": pd.Series(["x", "y", "z"], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "c": pd.Series([True, False, np.nan], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "d": pd.Series(["h", "i", np.nan], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "e": pd.Series([10, np.nan, 20], dtype=np.dtype("float")),
        "f": pd.Series([np.nan, 100.5, 200], dtype=np.dtype("float")),
    }
)

guessed_dtypes_df = df.convert_dtypes()

print(df.dtypes)
print(guessed_dtypes_df.dtypes)
```

which gives :

```py
# before dtypes      # after dtypes
a       int32        a      Int32
b      object        b     string
c      object        c    boolean
d      object        d     string
e     float64        e      Int64
f     float64        f    Float64
dtype: object        dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

First check which dtypes the dataframe holds per column.

```py
print(df.dtypes)
```

Then change all column value types.

```py
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(bool)
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(bool)
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(str)
df['D'] = df['D'].astype(int)
df['E'] = df['E'].astype(int)
```

Then check if if values properly converted.

```py
print(df.dtypes)
```

This should work. Let me know if it does not.

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Comment: Sorry but all my dtypes are objects, so I am sorry but your answer doesn't help me. I have checked it already. @richard-scholtens

Comment: No problem. Good luck!