# Is there any way to "extract" the dtype conversion functionality from pandas read_csv?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-inference

I have the following dataframe where all columns are of type objects.
My goal is to infer the real type of each column and convert.

I have found a "workaround" and saved it as csv and then loaded again.

Is there any way to use pandas read_csv type conversion functionality without the need to save and load the file?

```
{'A': {0: nan,
      1: nan,
      2: nan,
      3: nan,
      4: nan,
      5: nan,
      6: nan,
      7: 'true',
      8: nan,
      9: 'true'},
     'B': {0: nan,
      1: nan,
      2: nan,
      3: nan,
      4: nan,
      5: nan,
      6: nan,
      7: 'true',
      8: nan,
      9: 'true'},
     'C': {0: 'CustomersData',
      1: 'CustomersData',
      2: 'CustomersData',
      3: 'CustomersData',
      4: 'CustomersData',
      5: 'CustomersData',
      6: 'CustomersData',
      7: 'TestData',
      8: 'CustomersData',
      9: 'CustomersData'},
     'D': {0: '4014',
      1: '4014',
      2: '4014',
      3: '4014',
      4: '4014',
      5: '4014',
      6: '4014',
      7: '500',
      8: '4014',
      9: '500'},
     'E': {0: '8',
      1: '8',
      2: '8',
      3: '8',
      4: '8',
      5: '8',
      6: '13',
      7: '13',
      8: '8',
      9: '13'}}
```

Here is what I am doing to make it work:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
test_df.dtypes
```

Only when I am using this workaround pandas read_csv infers right the strings like '1' and '4044' as integers.
I have tried `convert_dtypes()` which turned all the columns to strings and `infer_objects()` that did nothing also.

Comment: When you convert to csv it probably is removing the single quotes and when you read it back read_csv takes them as integers. If you remove the single quotes when creating the dataframe convert_dtypes() will also assume they are integers.

Comment: @Jayvee thanks for the comment, but actually the above result is a pivot table of a long key-value table/dataframe. How can I config the pivot table to remove them?
Actually it turns to objects. Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in the pivot table, but you can always change the type explicitly in the dataframe, with astype, for example df['D'] = df['D'].astype(int)

Comment: @Jayvee but I don't know the type, this is the point that I need pandas to infer the type in this system. It will load automatically from a db, convert to pivot table, infer the types, fill missing values .... and do all other logic.

Comment: pandas bug is fixed and you can use pandas infer_objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments the actual process that benefit the infer type is to_csv as it strips the single quotes. Probably you can use some of the underlying to_csv classes and functions (DataFrameFormatter, DataFrameRenderer, CSVFormatter,etc.) but it would be more code and more risk of getting it wrong.
What you can do is write to and read from buffer, to avoid the IO overhead.

```
d={'A': {0: np.NaN,
      1: np.NaN,
      2: np.NaN,
      3: np.NaN,
      4: np.NaN,
      5: np.NaN,
      6: np.NaN,
      7: 'true',
      8: np.NaN,
      9: 'true'},
     'B': {0: np.NaN,
      1: np.NaN,
      2: np.NaN,
      3: np.NaN,
      4: np.NaN,
      5: np.NaN,
      6: np.NaN,
      7: 'true',
      8: np.NaN,
      9: 'true'},
     'C': {0: 'CustomersData',
      1: 'CustomersData',
      2: 'CustomersData',
      3: 'CustomersData',
      4: 'CustomersData',
      5: 'CustomersData',
      6: 'CustomersData',
      7: 'TestData',
      8: 'CustomersData',
      9: 'CustomersData'},
     'D': {0: '4014',
      1: '4014',
      2: '4014',
      3: '4014',
      4: '4014',
      5: '4014',
      6: '4014',
      7: '500',
      8: '4014',
      9: '500'},
     'E': {0: '8',
      1: '8',
      2: '8',
      3: '8',
      4: '8',
      5: '8',
      6: '13',
      7: '13',
      8: '8',
      9: '13'}}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)

from io import StringIO

buffer=StringIO()
df.to_csv(buffer, index=False)
df_new=pd.read_csv(StringIO(buffer.getvalue()))


df_new.dtypes
```

output:

```
A    object
B    object
C    object
D     int64
E     int64
dtype: object
```

you can then use convert_types to get the best inference:

```
df_new.convert_dtypes().dtypes
```

output:

```
A    boolean
B    boolean
C     string
D      Int64
E      Int64
dtype: object
```